# How to pass current node object to to command in telerik RadtreeviewItem in wpf

Tags: wpf, events, telerik, radtreeview, custom-button

I'm using Kendo Telerik RadTreeview control in WPF.. I have functionality that for each RadTreeViewItem node I'm adding a custom button which on command event show pop up.

I have added button and used it in `HierarchicalDataTemplate` as below

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="BuildingStructure"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Levels, Mode=TwoWay}"
                              ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource levelNodeStyle}">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition  Width="3*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition  Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" 
                       Width="250"
                       Text="{Binding StructureName , Mode=TwoWay}" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                       Panel.ZIndex="2"/>
            <Button
                Canvas.Left="10" 
                Canvas.Bottom="20"
                Panel.ZIndex="1"
                BorderThickness="0"
                BorderBrush="Transparent"
                Background="Transparent"
                 Foreground="White"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Grid.Column="1"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                Command="{Binding DataContext.AddLevelRadTreeCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=telerik:RadTreeView}}" 
                CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=radTreeView}"
                Margin="0 2 0 5">

                <Image
                    Width="20"
                    Height="20"
                   Source="/Project;component/Resources/Images/03-Add.png"/>
            </Button>
        </Grid>


    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

What I want is that on command event i need to add command parameter that will pass the current `RadTreeviewItem` data object which is assign to that node like below

```
StructId:1,
StructName:'Building A'....and so on...
```

Comment: You mean the datacontext of the treeview item? Binding datacontext relativesource self

Comment: @Andy im new to wpf, as well as telerik for wpf.. may i know how we can pass the current item to Command paramter

Comment: @Andy may i know how can we pass the parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you template out data into controls, the datacontext of the control becomes the viewmodel you're templating. Each of whatever in Levels becomes the datacontext of the treewview item produced.

DataContext is inherited down the visual tree.

Hence the datacontext of the button is the treeviewitem's.

Where you have

```
 CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=radTreeView}"
```

You want the datacontext the button is in. Which should be something like:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

Thinking about it a little more, it could also be

```
CommandParameter="{Binding}"
```

Comment: Thanks... both `CommandParameter="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"` and `CommandParameter="{Binding}"`  gave me the desired output